# Change data format to JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json, format

How do I change data format to JSON from python?

Python script:

```
progress = {'user': '170', 'user2': '220'}
level = {'user': '10', 'user2': '14'}
if progress.has_key('user'):
    a = progress['user']
    b = level['user']
    c = json('event': 'data', 'name': 'user', 'progress': a, 'level': b)
    self.send(net, c)
```

Javascript script:

```
var a = JSON.parse(c);
var user = a.user;
var progress = a.progress;
var level = a.level;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json
c = json.dumps({'event': 'data', 'progress': a, 'level': b})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, +1 for you :D

Answer (score 0):

From python

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(c)
```